# How can I install Glade 3.08?

Tags: installation, 11.10, ppa

Oneric comes with Glade 3.10 by default, and I need to install the older version. Is there any PPA, or some nice way to install it short of download the natty deb, pray that it works and pin it in synaptic?.

Some background: Glade 3.10 has dropped support of Gtk2.GUIs developed with Glade 3.10 don't work on older Linux distros and they can't be used with pygtk. I'm need my gtk programs to support 10.04.

Comment: I also wonder how is quickly going to work around this...

Comment: That is a very good question. Thanks for calling this issue to attention. g-i was just removed from Quickly a few days ago, but there is no doubt that it will replace PyGTK as quickly as possible.

Comment: If anybody is wondering, downloading and installing 11.04 deb, and pining it to avoid update works nicely for me. But I hope for a better way, one where updates are taken care.

Comment: I would vote you up without the rant. Rants are for forums and blogs. If you need to rant, do it on Ubuntuforums, or on a tech blog (preferably your own).

Comment: @Roldan: Ok, let's call the Rant Background and remove the part about how I love Qt ;). I believe that this info (call it rant or not) is valuable for the question as it adds context and discards some possible answers.

Comment: @JavierRivera please post your 3'rd comment as an actual answer so we can vote on it and mark it accepted!

Comment: @Jorge Castro:I was hoping for a better answer :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For 11.10**

The version packaged for 10.04 seems to work in oneric (11.10). You can use it to install the older Glade:

1. Download the .deb file, you can find it [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/glade), please click on your architecture.
2. Install the new deb by double-clicking on it.
3. Pin it to avoid it from updating.

You need to do it from the command line, pinning it from synaptic as I wrote in a comment will only work while updating in synaptic (as I learned today):

```
echo "glade hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Note that this approach is not very good: you will not receive security updates to glade (it doesn't look like a risky package) and if some package depends on the new glade version it's not going to be upgraded/installed.